# How can I write a program that takes a 32-bit IEEE754 representation of a float as a CL argument and outputs the float it represents in base-10?

Tags: c, terminal

I am having trouble with implementing this program. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (void)argc;

    // variables
    long signBit;
    long expVal = 0;
    double mantissa = 0.0;

    int expCounter = 0;
    int fracCounter = -1;

    char numString[33];
    char expBits[9];
    char fracBits[24];
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        numString[i - 1] = argv[1][i];
    }

    // sets signBit equal to first index from cl argument
    signBit = strtol(&argv[1][0], NULL, 10);
    strncpy(expBits, numString + 1, 7);
    strncpy(fracBits, numString + 9, 23);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        long bitVal = strtol(&expBits[i - 1], NULL, 10);

        // calculates e
        expVal += (bitVal * (long)pow(2, expCounter));
        expCounter++;
    }

    expVal -= 127; // adjusts expVal for bias

    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        int fracVal = (fracBits[i] == '1') ? 1 : 0;

        // calculates mantissa
        mantissa += (fracVal * pow(2, fracCounter));
        fracCounter--;
    }

    // convert to float in base 10
    double float_value = (pow(-1, signBit)) * (1 + mantissa) * (pow(2, expVal));

    printf("%.4f\n", float_value);
    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(i may have some errors due to quickly swapping some code out, but the gist remains the same). When I try to test this out in the terminal, for example:

```
./f32 00111111100000000000000000000000
```

I just get `-nan`. I'm not sure what I'm doing to cause this.

here are the assignment details:

> In f32.c, write a program that takes a 32-bit IEEE754 representation
> of a float as a command-line argument and outputs the float it
> represents in base-10.
>
> To account for floating-point error, when printing the float, use
> printf("%.4f\n", float_value) to print to 4 decimal places.
>
> These libraries should be useful:
>
> `string.h` `argv[1]` is a string. You are allowed to use `string.h`
>
> You do not have to convert the exponent bits to a base-10 integer
> yourself. Please use `strtol` to convert the exponent bits (`const char*`) to `long`. Pass `NULL` as the second argument. You may use
> `strlen` to get the length of a string. You may use `strncpy` to
> extract the exponent bits and mantissa bits from the 32-bit string. It
> can be used similarly to slicing in Python (`str[start:end]`) or
> Java's `substring(begIndex, endIndex)` method.
>
> `math.h` Please do not implement exponentiation yourself. For
> exponentiation, use `pow`

I basically just made some arrays to store the expBits, fracBits, and variables to store the signBits, expValue, and mantissa. I used a for loop to iterate through each index and calculate each part as necessary. I feel like I'm doing something incorrectly with properly converting the variables into the right type, but I'm not sure what to do to fix it.

Comment: Make sure that `long` is a big enough type to hold the significand (mantissa). It's a horrible type – it might be the size of `int` and it might be the size of `long long`. Best to avoid.

Comment: First thing first, you have a *binary* representation of something. That is, a string of 0s and 1s. Can you explain to your nearest rubber duck what `strtol(..., NULL, 10)` would do with such a string? Make sure the rôle of the third argument is thoroughly investigated.

Comment: @papayaaa, `strncpy(expBits, numString + 1, 7);` is a problem as `numStirng` is not certainly as _string_.  Assign a _null character_ first.  `for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {` -->  `for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {`

Comment: @papayaaa,  `strtol(&expBits[i - 1], NULL, 10)` is another problem as `expBits` is certainly not a _string_ - it lacks a _null character_.  Likewise for `fracBits`.  Stop using `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Code has *string* problems due to lack of *null characters*.

Replace

```
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        numString[i - 1] = argv[1][i];
    }

    // sets signBit equal to first index from cl argument
    signBit = strtol(&argv[1][0], NULL, 10);
    strncpy(expBits, numString + 1, 7);
    strncpy(fracBits, numString + 9, 23);
```

with

```
if (argc != 2 || strlen(argv[1] != 32) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument length <%s>\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// More late, but gotta-go-now.
...
```

Comment: im a bit confused as to why there aren't any null characters. Are they not automatically added to the end of an array since I allocated space for them?

Comment: @papayaaa, no.  With `char numString[33];`, all the elements of of array `numString` are uninitialized (indeterminant).

Comment: what about for a const char*?

Comment: @papayaaa `const char* example;` defines a  pointer.  The pointer value is uninitialized (indeterminant).  Without initialization or assignment, non-static objects are indeterminant, regardless of type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must think that reading ascii input in the command line is done in big endian, so digits are read from most signifiant digit to less one.

Your computer, althoug, can be big endian or little endian, so the best is to read the value as an integer (I selected `uint32_t` for it) and reinterpret memory as a `float` value.  For that, I used a trick, to use the `uint32_t` address as a pointer to `float` and let the computer do the work.

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float to_ieee754(uint32_t in)
{   
    /* the address of in parameter is cast to a (float *) and the
     * value pointed to is reinterpreted as a float, returning it
     * to the caller */
    return *(float *)&in;
}
```

the trick is here, data is read as an `uint32_t` and the value is reinterpreted and returned as a `float`.  As both data types have the same *endianness*, the reintepret works as expected.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    uint32_t value;
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "d:o:x:b:")) !=  EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'd': /* decimal input */
            value = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 10); break;
        case 'o': /* octal input */
            value = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 8); break;
        case 'x': /* hexadecimal input */
            value = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 16); break;
        case 'b': /* binary input */
            value = strtoul(optarg, NULL, 2); break;
        } /* swith */
        printf("to_ieee754(0x%08x) -> %13.7g\n",
                value, to_ieee754(value));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run, entering number in binary form is:

```
$ pru -b 00111111100000000000000000000000
to_ieee754(0x3f800000) ->             1
$ _
```

Comment: Pointer type punning is strict aliasing violation. Use `union` or `memcpy` instead.

Comment: Hmmmm... why?  I was not aware of that.  What is going to solve `memcpy` that this won't?  Where in _The C programming language_ (K&R first ed.) is that said?  Is that not C?  Is there any request to use last standard in the answers?  I'm a bit tired of this _You should follow the last (still unpublished) standard that will start working on the lang specs in the next decade_  Do you get my point? :)  Do you thing that an extra step converting the pointer to `(void *)` will do?

Comment: Compilers (try to) follow C standard, and are known to break code with undefined behaviour. Following standard gives you guarantee that program will work when you change from one compiler to another. (As much as guarantees can be given in real life.) There are no downsides for doing this correctly, so why not do so?

Comment: I agree on that, so please compile and run `main() { printf("Hello, world\n"); }`  (using old K&R first ed. code) and ignore the warnings, or use the lowest standard possible, and see what happens. Or compile `double sin(x) double x; { /* body of sin */ }`  and see.  I'm not going to discuss.  If you don't like my answer, you are free to downvote it.  Thanks for the feedback.